# Docker Micro service image Cant connect to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker, microservices

This is how I have configured MySQL in application.properties file

```js
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/roaming
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
  #spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

These are my images inside docker. There are three images. When I try to run the roaming image it cannot connect with my local machine MySQL server. Currently it run using Xampp server

```js
D:\Dialog\Applications\Roming\deployment>docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
roaming             v1                  b7cd90208bcb        17 hours ago        695MB
java                8                   d23bdf5b1b1b        2 years ago         643MB
```

I have an micro service image running inside a docker container and when I try following command 
**docker run -t roaming:v1** it gives the following error

```js
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar!/:5.4.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar!/:5.4.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar!/:5.4.2.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

and my Docker file as follows

```js
FROM java:8

ADD roaminglistener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar roaminglistener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","-jar","roaminglistener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: how did you configure for `connection localhost string` in code ?

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/roaming
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
  #spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

this is how I have configured in application.properties file @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: you need to create Inter Docker Container Communication Using Docker Networking

Comment: use this link https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-networking

Comment: Is the database running in a different container, or outside of Docker on the same host?

Comment: Outside of Docker same host @DavidMaze

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect from a container to host you have to run a container with the `--network host` options. More [details here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Answer (score 0):

use host.docker.internal instead of localhost in spring.datasource.url

Answer (score -1):

In container:

`127.0.0.1` is mean local container. if you want to connect MySQL server in host machine. (outside container but same host with container )

Should configure:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/roaming
```

change to :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:3306/roaming
```

`172.17.0.1` is default ip gateway of container network.